# How to clear cache via command line?

Tags: linux, cache

I want to clear all caches via command line on linux, how do you do this?

> Mem:   1033200k total,   175560k used,   857640k free,     5880k buffers
>   Swap:  2097144k total,        0k used,  2097144k free,    70804k cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

As root, of course.